# How can I display the key value from a map in a VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I have a `Map<string,list<sobject>>`. I want to display the value of Key i.e, the String in VF pages. I'm using

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m1[key]}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
```

to display the associated list, but unable to display the value of the Map-Key field itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the variable name of your key to display the value of that key. You haven't provided much of your VF markup, so as a guess given what I see:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m1[key]}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.name}" />
    <apex:column value="{!key}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:repeat value="{!m1}" var="key" >
        <apex:outputText value={!key}/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!m1[key]}" var="acctList" >
            <apex:column value="{!acctList.Name}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```